# How to Update column Num with an incremental number in Master-Detail with row_number()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update my column Acc.DocHeader.Num and Acc.DocItem.Num with an incremental number. I have:

```
UPDATE x
SET x.Num = x.newNum,x.iNum=x.newNum
FROM (
      SELECT Num,iNum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DocCreateDate ,DailyNum) AS newNum
      FROM (SELECT h.Num,h.DocCreateDate,h.DailyNum,i.Num iNum FROM Acc.DocHeader h INNER JOIN Acc.DocItem i ON i.DocHeaderRef = h.Id WHERE h.Year = 1395 AND h.BranchRef = 1) AS header
      ) x
```

Why do I get Derived table 'x' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables?

DocHeader Table :

```
Id      Num     Year        DocCreateDate       
-------------------------------------------------------
1       NULL        1396        2016-03-20
2       NULL        1395        2016-04-02
3       NULL        1395        2016-04-05
4       NULL        1395        2016-04-10
```

DocItem Table:

```
Id      Num     DocHeaderRef
----------------------------------------------
1       NULL        1
2       NULL        1
3       NULL        1
4       NULL        4
5       NULL        4
6       NULL        3
7       NULL        3
8       NULL        3
```

output:

DocHeader Table:

```
Id      Num     Year        DocCreateDate       
-------------------------------------------------------
1       1       1396        2016-03-20
2       1       1395        2016-04-02
3       2       1395        2016-04-05
4       3       1395        2016-04-10
```

DocItem Table:

```
Id      Num     DocHeaderRef
----------------------------------------------
1       1       1
2       1       1
3       1       1
4       3       4
5       3       4
6       4       3
7       4       3
8       4       3
```

Comment: Please show sample input and the output as it should appear after the update happens.

Comment: You have a `JOIN` in the subquery.  Only one table can be updated at a time.

Comment: @ElhamAzadfar . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  In that question, explain what you want to do, provide sample data, and desired results.  What you want to do is certainly possible, if inadvisable.

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to update columns from two different tables in a single `update` statement:

- `Num` comes from `Acc.DocHeader`
- `iNum` comes from `Acc.DocItem`

In SQL Server, you can only update one table at a time in an `UPDATE`.

You can update multiple tables in a single *transaction*.  You can also use the `OUTPUT` clause to capture the values from the rows being updated.  This answers the question of why you cannot do what you want.

I find your query a bit hard to follow -- and your question doesn't explain what you are trying to do -- so it is hard to suggest alternatives.